# Create nuget package for static assets

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, nuget, nuget-package

I'm exploring creating a Nuget package since I just started dabbling in .Net MVC and I have a custom theme that will be applied to any/all future applications will be built.

Does it make sense to create a Nuget package with all the static assets that will be needed? I'd prefer to use a package over manually copying files to each individual project since it'd be easier to keep track of what versions are installed.

What do best practices dictate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the same thing for my project to use my static CSS and JS files and apply them directly to other projects. There are two ways you can do that , one by using the Command line and here's a link for an article from the famous `Scott Hanselman`  [Command line version](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingANuGetPackageIn7EasyStepsPlusUsingNuGetToIntegrateASPNETMVC3IntoExistingWebFormsApplications.aspx)
the article is kind of outdated but it will give you an idea about the whole process from the prospective of a master in the field.

One other approach (the one i used myself ) is the GUI and here's a link for the instructions i followed: [Nuget package GUI](https://docs.nuget.org/create/using-a-gui-to-build-packages)